# OSMnx Tutorial 8 (Boeing) - Centrality

Tags: edges, osmnx

I have a two part question related to Boeing's OSMnx Tutorial 8 - Street network centrality analysis. Firstly, I have a knowledge question regarding edge closeness centrality and then a code-based question regarding edge betweenness centrality. My purpose is to calculate edge closeness and betweenness centrality around stations in various locations.

*1. Edge Closeness Centrality*

The following code works well for me:

```
# edge closeness centrality: convert graph to a line graph so edges become nodes and vice versa
edge_centrality = nx.closeness_centrality(nx.line_graph(G))

# list of edge values for the original graph
ev = [edge_centrality[edge + (0,)] for edge in G.edges()]

# color scale converted to list of colors for graph edges
norm = colors.Normalize(vmin=min(ev)*0.8, vmax=max(ev))
cmap = cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=cm.inferno)
ec = [cmap.to_rgba(cl) for cl in ev]
```

Question: Can anyone explain why in the normalisation code the mininum edge value is multiplied by 0.8 and the the maximum value is set at the maximum edge value? I am not too familiar with the literature so any advice would be appreciated.

*2. Edge Betweenness Centrality*

I am trying to calculate edge betweenness centrality in a similar way to the above code for edge closeness centrality on the same graph in the example. I have tried this and get the following:

```
# edge betweenness centrality
edge_bcentrality = nx.edge_betweenness_centrality(G)

# list of edge values for the orginal graph
ev1 = [edge_bcentrality[edge + (0,)] for edge in G.edges()]

# color scale converted to list of colors for graph edges
norm = colors.Normalize(vmin=min(ev1)*0.8, vmax=max(ev1))
cmap = cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=cm.inferno)
ec = [cmap.to_rgba(cl) for cl in ev1]

# color the edges in the original graph with betweeness centralities in the line graph
fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(G, bgcolor='k', axis_off=True, node_size=0, node_color='w', node_edgecolor='gray', node_zorder=2,
                        edge_color=ec, edge_linewidth=1.5, edge_alpha=1)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-6ee1d322067c> in <module>()
      1 # list of edge values for the orginal graph
----> 2 ev1 = [edge_bcentrality[edge + (0,)] for edge in G.edges()]
      3 
      4 # color scale converted to list of colors for graph edges
      5 norm = colors.Normalize(vmin=min(ev)*0.8, vmax=max(ev))

KeyError: (53090322, 53082634, 0)
```

If anyone advice on the the best way to calculate edge betweenness centrality I would be greatly appreciated, as I am still a novice. Also, it would be appreciated if someone could share the best way to proceed with normalisation.

Thank you for your time,

BC

Answer (score 0):

I applied this code and it works for me. Hope it helps.

```
#calculate betweenness
betweenness = nx.edge_betweenness(G=G, normalized=False)

# iterate over edges
edges = []
for i in betweenness.items():
    i = i[0] + (0,)
    edges.append(i)
for i,j in zip(edges,betweenness.keys()): 
    betweenness[i] = betweenness[j]
    del betweenness[j]

# color scale converted to list of colors for graph edges
norm = colors.Normalize(vmin=min(betweenness.values())*0.8, vmax=max(betweenness.values()))
cmap = cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=cm.viridis)
ec = [cmap.to_rgba(cl) for cl in betweenness.values()]

# color the edges in the original graph with betweeness centralities in the line graph
fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(G, bgcolor='w', axis_off=True, node_size=0, node_color='w', node_edgecolor='gray', node_zorder=2,
                        edge_color=ec, edge_linewidth=1.5, edge_alpha=1)
fig.show()
```